# contacts2.db is empty. But I have two contacts and can retrieve them using a content provider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firefox

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F. There are two contacts in my phone book. I can retrieve their IDs, display names, etc. using a content provider. However, when I pulled `contacts.db` from `./data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases`, I saw no data in the database.

**SQLite.**
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

```
C:\>sqlite3 C:\Users\Dmitriev_M\Downloads\contacts2.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>
```

**DB Browser for SQLite**
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

[image: SQLite Browser]

**Firefox SQLite Manager.**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... contacts2.db updates when Contacts app is shut down(i.e you kill Contacts app or restart your phone). Restarting my phone worked fine with my problem. To be sure you have the latest version of your db check the time of last modified in provider.contacts.

If you want to work on contacts.db and then  update it on your phone follow the steps from here: [adb: Update/rescan contacts without restarting the android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247770/adb-update-rescan-contacts-without-restarting-the-android-device)